# WPF Binding to converter for an Image (Bitmap) not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters, prism-5

I am having issues with an image not showing in a WPF control using a Converter to create the image from a local directory. Any direction on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Coms.Views.ImageDetailView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Coms.Converter"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Wheat">
<Control.Resources>
    <c:ImageDetailConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Control.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding icList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="imgBox" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtBlock2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding coordinates}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

class

```
public class ImageDetail
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Converter

```
public class ImageDetailConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IRuntimeConfigurations configs = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRuntimeConfigurations>();
        return new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(configs.rootImagePath, ((IImageDetail)value).fileName)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can return only path of image from Converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your converter returns a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which is WinForms, not WPF.

It should return a WPF `ImageSource` (e.g. a [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)) instead:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var imageDetail = (ImageDetail)value;
    var configs = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRuntimeConfigurations>();
    var path = Path.Combine(configs.rootImagePath, imageDetail.fileName);
    var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    return new BitmapImage(uri);
}
```

---

Note also that WPF provides built-in type conversion from `Uri` and `string` (containing a valid URI) to `ImageSource`, so that your converter could also return the `uri` or `path` value.